# Android: do I actually need to register in App Center to migrate from the HockeySDK?

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center, hockeyapp

I inherited a (fairly large) Android app; it's still in beta.

I recently got an email from Google Play:

```
"Action Required: Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies ...
We found your app is using a non-compliant version of Hockey SDK..."
```

OK. I learned that Microsoft acquired the company a few years ago and, last fall, transitioned the functionality to their (open source) [App Center SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/android) and deprecated the old HockeySDK.  Microsoft also published a nice, straightforward [Migration Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/transition/android-sdk-migration).

What the migration DOESN'T explicitly say is whether or not one MUST register on the App Center.

The new App Center SDK requires this:

```
AppCenter.start(getApplication(),
    "{Your App Secret}", 
    Analytics.class, Crashes.class, Distribute.class);
```

Q: The "App Secret" is *NOT* the old Hockey App ID (e.g. "00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff"), correct?

Q: The only way to get an "App Secret" is to register on the App Center, correct?

Q: I'm definitely *NOT* going to purchase the $50/month subscription to App Center.  Is there any downside to just commenting out the old Hockey SDK register (and unregister) calls from the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently facing the same issue but not because of HockeySDK.  We have migrated to AppCenter SDK over a year ago.  The issue is because of the "Distribute.class" that exists in both Hockey & AppCenter SDK.  You need to remove it for production build.

Please see Microsoft documentation about this here.  Hope this help

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/xamarin#remove-in-app-updates-for-google-play-builds